# Is this code is valid? if yes then on consol its showing an error

Tags: javascript

just see the code below

i just saw  an video on youtube about this by its not working in my case

```html
<head>
  <script>
    var r = document.getElementById("para").document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    console.log(r);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="nn">
    <span>demand</span>
    <span> demand 2</span>
    <b> block of bold</b>
  </p>
</body>
```

it should return the array containing all span tags in id="para".

Comment: Also, you need to fix `document.getElementById("nn").document.getElementsByTagName("span");` to be `document.getElementById("nn").getElementsByTagName...`

Comment: Change `para` to `nn` and remove the `.document` after `getElementById("para")`

Answer (score 1):

You dont have any element with the ID of "para" what you mean is probably the element with the id "nn". Also if u try to find some elements **within** another element then dont call that method on "document" but rather on the previously selected element like so:

```js
var r= document.getElementById("nn").getElementsByTagName("span");
console.log(r);
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>
<body>  
  <p id="nn">
      <span>demand</span>
      <span> demand 2</span>
      <b> block of bold</b>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```